# Can I transfer progress from different countries?

Tags: war-thunder

I just started this game and have advanced to Rank II in the American category.  I wanted to get a FW 190 and I was wondering if I can somehow transfer the progress I made in the American category to the German one.  Is this possible?  Or do I have to start all over again in the German category to get a FW 190?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Progress in each country's tech tree is separate.

The closest thing to what your describing would be to buy a premium vehicle and some gold. The research points you earn on that vehicle can then be converted to free RP which can be used in any nation.